# Showing price on legend when seats are unavailable

Tags: mobile-application, maps, booking

I'm designing a cabin booking feature in a travel app. What would be the best option if all the **Extra Legroom** seats (the unfilled ones) have been already taken.

1. To indicate as "unavailable " (like in the wireframe below)
2. Hide the legend of extra legroom.

would really appreciate any other suggestions as well.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure "unavailable" is the best wording, as it might hint to some temporary unavailability (of the system). "No seats left", "Fully booked", "All seats booked", "All seats taken" may be better options. The actual wording may be different if targeting the US, the UK or other markets.

Comment: You may want to try making a booking on existing sites using the same concepts. Pick flights with high relative prices to find those that are likely to have fully booked forward seats.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Showing the absence (unavailability) of a widespread and expected feature is clearer to the users, as extra legroom is a standard among airlines.

It's also clearer that the app is working as expected. If the extra legroom legend is not shown, it prompts some possible questions from the user:

- Is the app working correctly, did something not load?
- Does this airline not offer extra legroom?
- Is it me? I can't find any extra legroom seats...

Better off to show the legend; it's clearer, and doesn't waste the users time scanning the page to find what's unavailable. You can also test the language to see what's clearest ('no seats', etc.).